# Nesting Queries in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have recently started using SQL and am stuck when applying it to Access. My previous experience (limited) has been with PostgreSQL, and I understand that SQL in Microsoft Access requires you to nest queries into sub-queries, which I am not familiar with.

I believe the code in SQL (not for access would look something like this...)

```
select weeks, sum(sweets_eaten), count(distinct (sweet))
from table
group by weeks;
```

This would then give me a table where I would have the unique weeks, the sum of sweets eaten per week and the number of sweets per week.

Ideally, what the query would then do is also tell me the average sweets eaten per week by dividing the total sweets eaten per week by the number of sweets.

Does anyone know how to write a query so this will work in Microsoft Access?

Thanks!

Edited code, this is what I am entering

```
select f15, sum(f16), count(*)
from (select f15, sum(f16) as sum_sweets_eaten
from table1
group by f15, f16
) as t
group by f15;
```

For the average, would it be possible to do this in addition to the sum.

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, you can remove those redundant parentheses. I.e. simply do `count(distinct sweet)`.

Comment: what are `sweets`? and what make you think you need `DISTINCT` to count how many you eat?

Comment: I changed the table names, was feeling hungry so sweets came to mind

Answer (score 2):

The query you have written will not work in MS Access, because it does not support `count(distinct)`.

You can pre-aggregate to get the result you want:

```
select weeks, sum(sum_sweets_eaten), count(*)
from (select weeks, sum(sweets_eaten) as sum_sweets_eaten
      from table
      group by weeks, sweet
     ) as t
group by weeks;
```

To get the average, use `avg()` rather than `sum()`.

Comment: When I run it it asks me to enter a parameter for f16 (sum (sweets_eaten). This is the code I am entering into the query tool    
    select f15, sum(f16), count(*)
    from (select f15, sum(f16) as sum_sweets_eaten
    from table1
    group by f15, f16
     ) as t
    group by f15;

Comment: @Gandalfrandalf . . . I have no idea what your comment has to do either with your original question or my answer to it.  If you have another question, then ask it as a *new* question, not an edit to an existing question and not in a comment.